# How to prove (|a, b, c|) = (|a′, b′, c′ |) only if a=a'. b=b', c=c' when (|a, b, c|) = {{a}, {a, b}, {a, b, c}} and a, b, c are sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I'm strugglin to prove set theory problem.

Let's define $(|a, b, c|) = \{\{a\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, b, c\}\}$. Prove that when $a\neq b\neq c\neq a$ and $a'\neq b'\neq c'\neq a'$ then $(|a, b, c|)=(|a', b', c'|)$ defines that $a=a', b=b', c=c'$.

If we leave out the rule of member of the sets need to be different, could $(|a, b, c|)=(|a', b', c'|)$ be true even when $(a, b, c)=(a', b', c')$?.

I tried to prove this by showing three steps how firstly if $\{a\}=\{a'\}$ then $a=a$ must be true. Because pair $\{a, b\}=\{ a', b'\}$ and as stated before $a=a$ then must be $b=b'$. And because $\{a, b, c\}=\{ a', b', c'\}$ and $a=a', b=b'$ must be $c=c'$.

What goes wrong? Also is there any example set how $(|a, b, c|)=(|a', b', c'|)$ even if $(a, b, c) \neq (a', b', c')$?

Comment: Hint on one of your questions: consider that $(a, a, c) = \{ \{ a \}, \{ a, c \} \} = (a, c, c)$ with this definition.